# Why is the determinant necessary to find out the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Say I have a $2\times2$ matrix $A$:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\4&3\\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

To find the eigenvalues, I have to solve

$$Au = \lambda u,$$ where $u$ is a non-zero vector. Solving this I get

$$0 = \lambda u -Au \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = (\lambda*I_n -A)u.$$

Since $u$ is non-zero, $(\lambda I_n-A) = 0$. Why can't I then find the values of $\lambda$ for which this yields the null matrix? Why do I have to do
$$\det(\lambda I_n -A)=0$$

instead?

I think that to get a null vector you don't have to multiply it by a null matrix necessarily, so I figure it has something to do with that, but I don't understand why I have to use the determinant.

Comment: The formula is using the fact that $det A =0$ iff there is a non-zero vector in the kernel.

Comment: just because a matrix times a non-zero vector is zero doesn't mean the matrix is the zero matrix; e.g., $\pmatrix{2 & 2\\4 & 4}\pmatrix{1\\-1}=\pmatrix{0\\0}$

Comment: "Since  is non-zero, (−)=0" is false.  All we can conclude is that $\lambda I_n-A$ is singular.

Comment: You will remember that for integers and real numbers and such that if you have $a\times b = 0$ that implies that $a=0$ or that $b=0$.  Well... in more abstract settings we lose that [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain).  There are many scenarios where we can have $a\otimes b = 0$ for whatever multiplication $\otimes$ makes sense in that context where neither $a$ nor $b$ are zero.  These would occur in rings with [zero-divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor).

Comment: Loosely speaking, not all eigenvalues have an associated eigenvector. Take $A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $e_1$ is the only eigenvector (or rather the eigenspace has dimension one) whereas $A$ has two zero eigenvalues.

Comment: @Paul Right, and all eigenvectors are supposed to be non-zero. That makes sense...

Comment: We don't *have* to use determinants. In fact, Sheldon Axler has written an entire linear algebra book, *Linear Algebra Done Right*, which develops the whole theory of diagonalizability and eigenvalues specifically **without** the determinant.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Now why am I only finding this book now... thanks for the suggestion. Why doesn't he like determinants though?

Comment: It's not that he doesn't like them (the last chapter of the book introduces them). What he says is that: "Determinants are difficult, nonintuitive, and often defined without motivation.[...] In contrast, the simple determinant-free proofs presented here offer more insight. Once determinants have been banished to the end of the book, a new route opens to the main goal of linear algebra -- understanding the structure of linear operators."

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I hope that book sheds some light... I've been able to "learn" how to do things but I feel like I don't understand anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You partially answered your own question in saying that "I think that to get a null-vector you don't have to multiply it by a null-matrix necessarily".

The other part is that you don't *need* to use the determinant.
If you find an eigenvalue however you do, that's good. You can try to solve $Av = \lambda v$, you can do it by inspection, you can do it by heavenly inspiration (provided you check, ha!).

The fact of matter is, that for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$.
This is because if an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ has a nonzero vector $v$ in its kernel, then that $v$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $0$.
It follows that $\det M$, as the product of $M$'s eigenvalues, is $0$.
The thing is, this also goes in reverse: if $\det M = 0$, then some eigenvalue must be $0$, and so there must be nonzero vector in $M$'s kernel.

Comment: "This is because if an n×n matrix M has a nonzero vector v in its kernel, then that v is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue 0. " could you expand on that?

Comment: This is by the definition of eigenvector and eigenvalue. A nonzero vector $v$ is an eigenvector of $M$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ if $Mv = \lambda v$. Thus, if $v\neq 0 $ and $Mv = 0$ then $Mv = 0\cdot v$ and hence $v$ is an eigenvector of $M$ associated to the eigenvalue $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to say $(\lambda I_n - A)u=0$ and $u\ne 0 \implies \lambda I_n-A=0$,

but that's not true, as the example  $\pmatrix{2 & 2\\4 & 4}\pmatrix{1\\-1}=\pmatrix{0\\0}$, where $\lambda=-1$,  shows.

What *is* true is that $\det(\lambda I_n-A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are *not* after the null matrix. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $5$ and $-1$ but neither $A-5\operatorname{Id}$ nor $A+\operatorname{Id}$ are the null matrix. The numbers $5$ and $-1$ are the numbers $\lambda$ for which the equation $(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id}).\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ has non-null solutions. And those $\lambda$'s are precisely the solutions of the equation $\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=0$.

Comment: I think you meant the numbers $5$ and $-\color{red}1$

Comment: Sure! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for numerical work with matrices  much bigger than $2 \times 2$, you do **not** want to compute or solve the characteristic polynomial.  It is numerically unstable.  There are much more efficient and stable numerical methods, e.g. the QR algorithm.

Comment: a reference for  the QR algorithm would be great.

Comment: @CroCo D. Serre, [Matrices: Theory and Applications](https://books.google.com/books?id=vY_xBwAAQBAJ), section 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

We want $(\lambda∗I_n−A)u = 0$ with $u \neq 0$. If we assume $(\lambda∗I_n−A)$ is invertible, then $u = (\lambda∗I_n−A)^{-1}*0 = 0$ which goes against our requirement for $u \neq 0$. Hence, we want $(\lambda∗I_n−A)$ to be a non-invertible matrix. A square matrix is non-invertible iff it's determinant is $0$. This leads us to the conclusion that $det((\lambda∗I_n−A)) = 0$ for non-zero eigenvectors.

Answer (score -1):

Answering this question is actually quite simple. Putting aside determinant for a moment, lets focus on solving homogeneous systems. Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the following homogenous system has a **trivial** solution
$$
Bx=0
$$
If and only if the row reduced echolen form (rref) of $B$ is the identity matrix $I$, right?. In other words, the rank of $B$ is full (i.e. rank($B$) = $n$). For **nontrivial** solutions, we need $\text{rank}(B) < n$. This case occurs only if $B$ is singular (i.e. $\text{rref}(B) \nrightarrow I $). Now Let's return to the eigenvalues problem. We need to find the nontrivial solutions for the following homogenous system

$$
\underbrace{(\lambda I - A)}_{B} x = 0. 
$$
The matrix $(\lambda I - A)$ must be singular. "One way" to check if the square matrix is singular is $\det(B) = 0$; therefore, we have
$$
\det(\lambda I - A) = 0. 
$$